# How to render a (Twitter Bootstrap) grid using Ember.js and Handlebars.js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I’m having a hard time figuring a way to render the following markup using Ember.Handlebars:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">Item #1 (row #1 / column #1)</div>
  <div class="span4">Item #2 (row #1 / column #2)</div>
  <div class="span4">Item #3 (row #1 / column #3)</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">Item #4 (row #2 / column #1)</div>
  <div class="span4">Item #5 (row #2 / column #2)</div>
  <div class="span4">Item #6 (row #2 / column #3)</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">Item #7 (row #3 / column #1)</div>
</div>
```

Using pure JavaScript, I’d have done something like this:

```
var array = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6', 'Item 7'],
    output = '<div class="row-fluid">';

for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
  output += '<div class="span4">' + i + '</div>';

  if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
    output += '</div><div class="row-fluid">';
  }
}

output += '</div>';
```

Ideally, I’d put this in a custom Handlebars helper (thus removing the logic from the template) but [Ember documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/) only explains how to write simple helpers and I really don’t know how to write a more complex block helper without losing the property bindings.

Does anyone know the best way to use Twitter Bootstrap’s grid system with a collection of Ember models?

Thank you in advance! Best regards,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, here is a pretty clean way to handle this scenario.

Here is the template:

```
{{#each post in posts}}
  {{#if post.first}}
    <div class="row-fluid">
  {{/if}}
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="post">
        {{post.title}}
      </div>
    </div>
  {{#if post.lastOfRow}}
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
  {{/if}}
  {{#if post.last}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

And the corresponding controller:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  posts: function () {
    var length = this.get('length');

    return this.map(function (post, i) {
      // Checks if it’s the last post
      if ((i + 1) == length) {
        post.last = true;
      } else {
        post.last = false;

        // Checks if it’s the first post
        if (i == 0) {
          post.first = true;
        } else {
          post.first = false;
        }

        // Checks if it’s the last post of a row
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
          post.lastOfRow = true;
        } else {
          post.lastOfRow = false;
        }
      }

      return post;
    });
  }.property('content.@each')
});
```

This may also be useful to generate tables (with `<td>` nested in `<tr>`)… Even though I ended up using kiwiupover’s solution! ;-)

Regards,

D.

Answer (score 4):

G'day Dave

Instead of useing rows and div to make a block grid try using an "unordered list"

The HTML

```
<ul class="row-fluid block-grid-3">
  <li>Item #1 (row #1 / column #1)</li>
  <li>Item #2 (row #1 / column #2)</li>
  <li>Item #3 (row #1 / column #3)</li>
  <li>Item #4 (row #2 / column #1)</li>
  <li>Item #5 (row #2 / column #2)</li>
  <li>Item #6 (row #2 / column #3)</li>
  <li>Item #7 (row #3 / column #1)</li>
</ul>
```

Then the CSS would look like this.

```
ul.block-grid-3 {
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.block-grid-3 > li {
   width: 33.33333%;
   float: left;
   padding: 0 12px 12px;
   display: block;
   height: auto;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
   clear: left;
}
```

Then if you wanted to change to four blocks you can can change the css to:

```
ul.block-grid-4 > li {
   width: 25%;
   float: left;
   padding: 0 12px 12px;
   display: block;
   height: auto;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}  
ul.block-grid-4 > li:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
   clear: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kiwiupover/BHB9m/) a more robust solution.

You can also check out this ember app [Open-pos](http://open-pos.herokuapp.com/#/orders/72) the products are layout using this method.

Zurb's css framework "foundation" as great solution called [block-grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block-grid.html). This there system it is super easy to change the 3 up grid other number with just a small change in the css. you could drop in the [block grid code](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_block-grid.scss) into your bootstrap scss. If you have any questions let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Hey,

Thank you so much for your response and especially for taking the time to set up a Fiddle!

The markup you suggest is both simpler and more semantic than Bootstrap’s and usually I prefer to use something like this. But in this case, I’m working on a project for which Bootstrap is used and I wanted to stick to it.

Moreover I think that it’s often a bad sign when the HTML must be tailored to the (front- or back-end) framework rather than the opposite, don’t you think?

Anyway, thank you very much for your response and for these great examples! Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works well, but if you have `posts` that are dynamic the rows and spans will be re-drawn any time the `posts` model / property changes.  This might be OK, if the content is small, but in my case I have a chart for each block and it's readily apparent when they all are redrawn at the same time.

In my case, I decided to override the bootstrap css; however, you would want to account for various screen sizes via additional media queries.

Here's the rules to target the largest grid and ensure that there are 3 `span4`s (note this was BS 2.3.2) correctly aligned on each "row", but inside a single `row-fluid`:

```
  .row-fluid [class*="span4"]:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .row-fluid [class*="span4"]:nth-of-type(n+4) {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```