# Bootstrap 3 grid in Ember with #each using relational models

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, ember-data

I am looking for an implementation of the bootstrap grid with rows and device sensitive columns within the {{#each}} iterator of the Ember Handlebar template.

There doesn't seem to be a way to look up the iterator index value to add bootstrap rows.

I found this thread, but the solution doesn't seem to work with relational models.
[How to render a (Twitter Bootstrap) grid using Ember.js and Handlebars.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156458/how-to-render-a-twitter-bootstrap-grid-using-ember-js-and-handlebars-js)

My model has 2 objects (populated from the server using RESTAdapter).

1. Container Object

   - id
   - name
   - pictures (linked using DS.hasMany)
2. Item Object

   - id
   - name
   - container (linked using DS.belongsTo)

I need this when viewing a single container which may contain many items. Here is the desired output (edited from other SO issue):

```
<h2>Container Name</h2>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-4">Item #1 (row #1 / column #1)</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Item #2 (row #1 / column #2)</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Item #3 (row #1 / column #3)</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-4">Item #4 (row #2 / column #1)</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Item #5 (row #2 / column #2)</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Item #6 (row #2 / column #3)</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-4">Item #7 (row #3 / column #1)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have looked at using something like this http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/ However they dont seem to have the grid implementation yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884960/how-to-get-index-in-handlebars-each-helper

Comment: @Oliver Thanks for the link.  {{@index}} is not available in Ember. I found an internal way of doing it with {{_view.contentIndex}}. However it isnt much use with the example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Handlebars #each syntax in Ember now supports exposing the current index on each iteration

```
{{#each model as |article index|}}
  <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
  <h2>{{index}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```