# How do I output an opening or closing tag in an ember handlebars if block?

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation, handlebars.js

I am trying to use a Zurb Foundation grid in ember, and I can't figure out how to get my template to properly insert row start/end tags with multiple columns.

I have a controller properly spitting out "isFirstOfRow, isLastOfRow", but I can't figure out how to get Ember's version of handlebars to spit out unbalanced opening/closing tags. My logic will balance them, but they won't be balanced in each iteration of the `{{#each}}` block.

My template looks like this:

```
{{#each item in items}}
    These are all working perfectly, thanks to my mad math skills:
    {{item.firstOfRow}}
    {{item.lastOfRow}}

    The problems start here:
    {{#if item.firstOfRow}}
        <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4">
            I shouldn't be closed immediately
    {{/if}}

    <li>
        <a href="/items/{{unbound id}}">
          <h4>{{item.title}}</h4>
          <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        </a>
    </li>

    ...and continue here:
    {{#if item.lastOfRow}}
            I should have been closed here.
            Ember outputs an unbalanced closing tag correctly,
            it's the opening that has the problem!
        </ul>
    {{/if}}

{{else}}

    This is irrelevant, and is working perfectly...
    <ul><div class="text-center"><strong>No items found</strong></div></ul>

{{/each}}
```

It keeps immediately closing the `<ul>` tag at the top.

Is there a way to cause the ember template to output the HTML, but treat it dumbly, as if it were plain text?

**Edit:** after the comments/answer I received, here's the intended template expansion after all the magic takes place. It is dictated by the way CSS grid systems typically work (and the way Zurb works in particular). The classes are approximations, the element hierarchy is the important part:

```
<div class="table">
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="/items/item1573">
        <h4>First item</h4>
        <p>It's an item!</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="/items/item4953">
        <h4>Second item</h4>
        <p>It's another item!</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="/items/item4333">
        <h4>Third item</h4>
        <p>Item item item</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="/items/item53213">
        <h4>Fourth item</h4>
        <p>Items galore</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the controller code I'm using to drive the template. It is outputting its properties perfectly. I'm just showing it to demonstrate the complete end to end solution I'm trying in case you guys have a better suggestion for the intended markup:

```
ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
    itemController: 'item'
    items: (->
        length = @get 'length'
        @map (item, i) ->
            item.last = i + 1 == length
            item.first = i == 0
            item.firstOfRow = i % 2 == 0
            item.lastOfRow = (i + 1) % 2 == 0
            item
    ).property 'content.@each'
```

Comment: Would definitely go with @Kalman Hazins' answer below.  Allowing your controller state to possibly force your view to output bad markup is simply bad design, and there are far more concise ways of writing the template :-)

Comment: @mpowered: See my comment on his answer. I'm not sure this template is as simple as you guys are suggesting. If you can figure out how to write the template more concisely, then awesome. The alternative *I* can think of is to do row grouping at the array controller level, which seems even more gross to me (i.e.  `item.firstColumn.title` `item.firstColumn.description` `item.secondColumn.title` etc).

Comment: I made several edits to clear up the code/question. It's still the same fundamental problem with my approach/ember's handlebars implementation, so the answer should be identical.

Comment: And here's a nearly identical solution to the one I'm trying to implement that *used* to work in Ember, seemingly before some ember templating system refactors :) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16213602/232593

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to display unbalanced HTML tags inside the `if` helper. But, if I understand what you are trying to do - you are working way too hard. :)

Why not just wrap the whole thing inside an `if/else` helper and display items if the array is not empty (if condition is true) and display a message if the array is empty? An empty array will evaluate to `false`.

```
    {{#if items}}
      <ul>
        {{#each item in model}}
        <li>{{item}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{ else }}
      No items
    {{/if}}
```

See a working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kilefi/1/edit)

**UPDATE**

You can also have a nested `each` with an `if` such as this:

```
  {{#each row in model}}
    {{#if row.items }}
      <ul>
        {{#each item in row.items }}
          <li>{{item}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
```

See a working example [here](http://jsbin.com/kilefi/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: The intention of the template is to write: `<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><ul><ul><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li></ul>`. The grid system I'm using requires each row of the grid be wrapped in an element.

Comment: I edited the question to make that markup more clear, and show the controller that I'm using in my iteration that is making those magic properties.

Comment: The `if` isn't the important part, really. The real work in your suggested solution is making is so I can nest the loops in the template by returning a two-dimensional from the controller. Do you have an easy way to go about that? I'm using a firebase datasource which returns one dimensional lists, so I'd need to figure out the controller logic to transform it.

Comment: See my new answer based off your edit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27831781/232593 - do you know of a simpler way to do what I'm doing in the controller? Is there a way to handle that in the template, like I was originally trying to do?

Comment: I just realized while playing with codepen for another question that I don't actually NEED a `<ul>` around each and every item. The block grid framework is smart enough to automatically create rows for me! I was obsessing over ensuring I had a DOM row for every logical row, [as you need with the regular grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) since it needs to add up to 12 :) I didn't realize the same didn't apply to the block grid. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwWRWa

Answer (score 2):

This may be necessary if you use a regular grid (for example, if you have uneven columns or do interesting row alternation style/sizes), but is absolutely unnecessary if you're using the block-grid.

See this fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwWRWa

If you're using the block grid, just do a plain old `{{#each ...}}` with a vanilla array controller and you'll be golden!

---

I solved this by changing the way I was outputting data from my controller, ala [Kalman's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828508/232593).

Base controller code:

```
`import Ember from "ember";`

GridController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
    rows: (->
        width = @get 'rowWidth'
        height = @get('length') / @get('rowWidth')
        result = Ember.A(Ember.A() for i in [0..height])
        @forEach (item, index) ->
            result[Math.floor(index / width)].push(item)
        return result
    ).property 'content.@each'

`export default GridController;`
```

Specific controller code (repeat for as many grids as you need):

```
`import GridController from "./grid";`

BlahDeeBlahsController = GridController.extend
    itemController: 'blah-dee-blah'
    rowWidth: 4

`export default BlahDeeBlahsController;`
```

Template code:

```
{{#each row in rows}}
<ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4">
    {{#each item in row}}
    <li>
        <a href="/items/{{unbound id}}">
            <div class="panel text-center">
                <h4>{{item.title}}</h4>
                <p>{{item.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
{{else}}
<ul><div class="text-center"><strong>No items found</strong></div></ul>
{{/each}}
```

I still think there could be a cleaner/more magical way to build the controller code than what I came up with, but this seems to be solving the problem.